# How do I force "top" command to show processes greater than PID XXX

Tags: command-line, top

I want top command to show processes that are greater than PID xxx
is there a switch that can do that? also can I sort the output based on the PID number instead of the CPU usage?

Comment: You can press `h` to see the various options your `top` supports.

Comment: Hinklo, my comment below may have passed unnoticed - could you please add the output of `top -v` and `dpkg -S $(which top)` to your post? I suspect you may be using some unusual implementation. The normal way to solve your problem should work, as can be seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tE1le-9lALc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `top` runs every 3s.

You can monitor processes greater than PID XXX by using the `watch` command and `top` in batch mode (with `-b`, for 1 iteration with `-n 1` and sorted by PID with `-o PID`):

```
watch -n 3 "top -o PID -b -n 1 | perl -ne '/^\s+(\d+)\s+/; print if (not \$1 or \$1 > 5000)'"
```

Where for example 5000 is my threshold:

[image]

Tested on 14.04

Answer (score 4):

You can run `top -o PID` to sort by PID (or hit the `<` key several times while top is running to move the sort column to the right, until it's sorting by PID).

You can filter PIDs interactively while top is running by hitting the `o` key and typing `PID>1000` or whatever minimum value you want, followed by enter.

Comment: It didn't work, any other way?

Comment: @Hinklo This works, and this is the way you would do it. Instead of looking for "some other way", I'd investigate why it doesn't work for you. What *exactly* happened (i.e, what does "it didn't work" mean)? Are you referring to the sorting, or the filtering? or did neither work? You may have done something wrong. Did you try the `PID>1000` filter as suggested by Stephen for a start? You can also see a list of active filters by hitting Ctrl+o. Do you see the `PID>1000` one? Pay attention to upper-/lowercase: `pid>1000` will *not* work.

Comment: This is what I get when I press the letter "o" , small letter

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAbiIwr-7wU

Comment: I can confirm the filter does not work on Ubuntu 14.04. And no, it is not clear why, it functions with other fields.

Comment: @Hinklo and @LuísdeSousa, here's what happens when I press the small letter "o" when in `top`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tE1le-9lALc. As you can see, it works like a charm. In Ubuntu 14.04, by default `/usr/bin/top` comes with the package [procps](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/procps), currently at version 3.3.9. I can confirm (see my video) that the `o`-hitting method works with this version. Maybe you replaced the default version of `top` with some other implementation? Can you issue `top -v` and `dpkg -S /usr/bin/top` and `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/top | cut -d: -f1)`?

Comment: `$ top -v
  procps-ng version 3.3.9` `$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/top
procps: /usr/bin/top` `$ apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/top | cut -d: -f1)
procps:
  Installed: 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.3.9-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
`

Comment: @LuísdeSousa That's the same version I use, and I have not experienced any problems with the PID filter. (I assume Hinklo is using another version, since something entirely different happens for him when he presses "o".) In your case though, you can add filters just fine, but you're saying the PID filter is not working for you, right? What exactly doesn't work about it? Does it have the wrong effect, or no effect at all? Do you get an error message? Again, as you can see in the video link in my last comment, it *should* be working just fine. What PID filter(s) did you try to add, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to try out [htop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/htop)

Some examples are [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/09/linux-htop-examples/)